# what is the best CMS for member login and job posting

Tags: cms

Hi I have worked in wordpress and joomla  but i am confusing to choose CMS.. which one is suitable for my requirements. Please read requirements and suggest me some CMS. Thanks in advance

Directory which will list all of our members, with the option to sort by company name and category (eg manufacturer, supplier, developer, EPC, legal, accountant, education, government etc). Some members will fall into one or more of these categories. The directory should contain the following:

Name of company
Contact person
Phone number
Mobile number
Address
Category
Membership Type

Members should be able to add/edit their details so each member will need to be given a log-in and password.
Admin should approve/manage the memberships.

B) Job Posting
Job posting section – members can post job opening

Comment: The best one is the one you know how to use and write code for.

Comment: i know only basic level in wordpress and joomla.i didnt know which one is suitable for..

Answer (score 0):

You could do most of this with WordPress. The Job posting section could just be a page of a category of messages. And you could use the build in settings to enable the admin to accept new members. The admin can also grant them privileges. The [Connections Business Directory plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/connections/screenshots/) enables you to add members to your system.

I hope this is what you are looking for.